# Scala datetime between nscala-time and Java 8 data time

Tags: java, scala, playframework, jodatime, nscala-time

If before Java 8 releases, definitely I will choose nscala-time for my scala play project.

However since Java 8 releases, recommending using Java 8 data and time instead of joda time for Java project.

So how about for Scala project? Should we stick using nscala-time or switch? If using Java 8 date and time, need to use mutable.

Also, which library has good support for play json library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 time library (`java.time`) types are immutable; Joda Time actually has some mutable classes for specific use-cases. There is also [a Scala wrapper](https://github.com/reactivecodes/scala-time) for `java.time` which can be used together with a backport of `java.time` for Java 7. I have no experience with Play JSON, but according to [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework-dev/KSvztb36oSI),

> We should consider migrating to the JSR-310 types internally in Play 3.0 and recommending using java.time._ types in the documentation. It seems like the Reads/Writes implementations we have for those are pretty reasonable. We just need to make sure we add support for those types in other parts of the APIs
>
> > But, currently at least the implementation in 2.4.2 for java.time.Instant Reads/Writes is buggy and I'm trying to get this fixed. So, maybe you want to join the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/VFMTGPCW7Hc

so it seems using nscala-time (or Joda directly) makes more sense for now, especially if you use other parts of Play, not just JSON.

Comment: the joda time you mean is nscala-time which is the wrapper, right? thanks